# Variable with CSV sctructure to multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, csv, tcl

I have a csv structure preloaded to a variable from a file just for testing because the source will come from a command result.

The variable contents are like:

```
ID,Date,Who,Text
123,2023-01-01,John,"This is a single line."
234,2023-02-01,Jane,"This is line 1
line2
the line 3 is this one"
457,2023-04-06,Mary,"Another single line."
```

The line that says "line2" maybe empty or not.

So, how do I parse the contents of the variable to an array?
I wanted the array to be like this:

```
$ set arraycsv(123)
2023-01-01 John {This is a single line.}
$ set arraycsv(234)
2023-02-01 Jane {This is line 1 line2 the line 3 is this one}
```

... and then this array to be processed by the rest of the code.
The 3 lined quote will have to be converted to remove any "" """ newlines.

I looked at the csv package but I am kinda confused because I never used it before.
Any help would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key [`csv` procs](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md) you want are `split` (obvs) and `iscomplete`

```
package require csv

set args [lassign $argv filename]
set fh [open $filename r]
array set arraycsv {}
gets $fh header

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    while {![csv::iscomplete $line]} {
        append line " " [gets $fh]
    }
    set fields [csv::split $line]
    if {[llength $fields] == 0} then continue
    set arraycsv([lindex $fields 0]) [lrange $fields 1 end]
}

parray arraycsv
```

More code needs to be done to protect infinite loops when the *last line* of the CSV file is incomplete.

---

Oh, since you already have the data in a variable

```
array set arraycsv {}
set lines [split $contents \n]
set len [llength $lines]

# starting at 1 to skip the header line
for {set i 1} {$i < $len} {incr i} {
    set line [lindex $lines $i]
    while {![csv::iscomplete $line]} {
        incr i
        append line " " [lindex $lines $i]
    }
    set fields [csv::split $line]
    if {[llength $fields] == 0} then continue
    set arraycsv([lindex $fields 0]) [lrange $fields 1 end]
}

parray arraycsv
```

Comment: Most of us would expect simple line for the 4th field but I noticed that it could contain weird format like newlines. I will give the second code a try which is more suitable for online fetching I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: If the data is coming over the network, keep `\r\n` line endings in mind.